# Why spark (scala API) agg function takes expr and exprs arguments?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, variadic-functions

Spark API `RelationalGroupedDataset` has a function `agg`:

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
def agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*): DataFrame = {
  toDF((expr +: exprs).map {
    case typed: TypedColumn[_, _] =>
      typed.withInputType(df.exprEnc, df.logicalPlan.output).expr
    case c => c.expr
  })
}
```

Why does it take two separate arguments? Why can't it take just `exprs: Column*` ?
Has someone an implicit function that takes one argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to make sure that you specify at least one argument.

Pure varargs cannot do that, you could call the method without any arguments.

Comment: but `select` and `groupBy` also take varags only, why this difference?

Comment: you can still pass empty aggregations using the `Map` API

Answer (score 1):

I tried to imagine how it would be using `cats.data.NonEmptyList` (requires `cats-core` dependency: `libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.1.1"`):

```
import cats.data.NonEmptyList

implicit class RelationalGroupedDatasetOps(
  private val rgd: RelationalGroupedDataset
) {
  def aggOnNonEmpty(nonEmptyColumns: NonEmptyList[Column]): DataFrame =
    rgd.agg(nonEmptyColumns.head, nonEmptyColumns.tail:_*)

  def aggUnsafe(columnList: List[Column]): DataFrame = {
    val nonEmptyColumns = NonEmptyList.fromListUnsafe(columnList)
    rgd.agg(nonEmptyColumns.head, nonEmptyColumns.tail:_*)
  }
}
```

For **scala 2.12** using std lib `List`:

```
implicit class RelationalGroupedDatasetOps(
  private val rgd: RelationalGroupedDataset
) {
  def aggUnsafe(aggColumns: List[Column]): DataFrame =
    aggColumns match {
      case ::(head, tail) => rgd.agg(head, tail:_*) 
      case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "aggColumns parameter can not be empty for aggregation"
      )
    }
}
```

using example:

```
import Implicits.RelationalGroupedDatasetOps

// some data with columns id, category(int), amount(double)
val df: DataFrame = ???
df.groupBy("id")
  .aggUnsafe(
    df.columns.filter(c => c != "id").map(c => sum(c))
  ) // returns aggregated DataFrame
```